# meaning of 結構がち

Tags: grammar, translation, words

これ結構がちかもやで

I was reading a text and I stumbled upon this... What does 結構がち mean? I know that ーがち means "to be apt to..." and so on, but I don't know how to translate 結構 here.

Answer (score 5):

This がち doesn't mean "to be apt to..." but serious. It can be rephrased as 本気, 真剣.

This 結構 means "rather, quite". So this phrase means "This may be quite serious".